# Parse Textfile to get number

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I have a textfile with several different rows. I want to get the number of the row which start with CellNumber e.g.

file.txt

```
Hello there
my name is struct
CellNumber 4.0050
I am from Timbuktu
```

How can I store the number 4.005 in a variable?

This is my try:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (file.txt) do (
    echo %%A

    IF "%%A:~0,10%"=="CellNumber" (
        set var=%var:~-5%
    )
)

echo result: %var
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning a value from a text file to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18800484/assigning-a-value-from-a-text-file-to-a-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

way too complicated. Use `find` or `findstr` to get the desired line and proper tokens and delimiters to parse that line. All you need is:

```
for /F "tokens=2" %%A in ('type file.txt^|findstr /b "CellNumber"') do set var=%%A
echo result: %var%
```

read `for /?` for tokens and delimiters.

this avoids/corrects the four errors in your code:
- you can't use substrings with `for`variables (`%%A`)
- you need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)
- variables are referenced with `%var%`, not `%var`
- in your example, you need *six* chars, not five